# How to populate a database as soon as user uploads a file

Tags: html, mysql

So Ive a code where in user uploads a video file from a certain directory.

-Now as soon as the user uploads the file, I want a table to be created with the name of the file as the name of table and exactly three columns named

`ID(primary),type(varchar20), timestamp(float)`

-Secondly, the page should show the table name created and there should be an option to delete the table if the user wants to.

My video upload and play code goes as below

```
<h1>HTML5 local video file player example</h1>
<div id="message_"></div>
<input type="file" accept="video/*"/>
<video controls autoplay></video>


<script>
(function localFileVideoPlayer() {
        'use strict'
  var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL
  var displayMessage = function (message, isError) {
    var element = document.querySelector('#message_')
    element.innerHTML = message
    element.className = isError ? 'error' : 'info'
  }
  var playSelectedFile = function (event) {
    var file = this.files[0]
    var type = file.type
    var videoNode = document.querySelector('video')
    var canPlay = videoNode.canPlayType(type)
    if (canPlay === '') canPlay = 'no'
    var message = 'Can play type "' + type + '": ' + canPlay
    var isError = canPlay === 'no'
    displayMessage(message, isError)

    if (isError) {
      return
    }

    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file)
    videoNode.src = fileURL
  }
  var inputNode = document.querySelector('input')
  inputNode.addEventListener('change', playSelectedFile, false)
})()
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to create a whole **table** for each file? Why not add one row per file to a common table? And what have you tried to solve this? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase actually there are three columns that I need per file, Ive simplified my query. Secondly I dont know how to integrate html and sql. Im a python gal and sql noob. Even getting this video player code work with my scenario was a big feat for me. Ive pasted only the relevant code here, where Im stuck

Comment: It's always good to learn new languages, but you won't get any far using HTML alone, as this is only interpreted in the browser. You should look up some server-side techniques like PHP or Python to solve that problem

Comment: @NicoHaase He doesn't want to create a new table, but a new DATABASE :D Anyway, if you use html, you need a form with enctype="multipart/form-data", then an file type input for a file uploading. I almost wrote a PHP code, but I don't know which language do you want to process it

Comment: @kry I just want to be able to differentiate between the data for each of the 200 video files Ive got.  So I thought seperate DB is the way to go :-D

Comment: @kry php/ajax is fine with me

Comment: There is a hierarchy to SQL. At top, are the databases, in databases are tables, in tables rows. Nico asked if inserting the data of an uploaded file as a row is enough.

Comment: @kry I guess One DB for all entire video directory , and 200 separate tables for the 200 videos would be fine (each having 3 columns)

Comment: Ok, HTML sends automatically the data as I mentioned before. On PHP side, it will arrive as a $_FILES['input_name'] array, from which you can take the $_FILES['input_name']['name'] as the name. Insert that name to your SQL query, which I highly recommend to insert rows, and do not create tables, unless necessary.

Answer (score 1):

(Mercilessly stolen from php.net https://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

```
<?php
$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile) && $_FILES['userfile']['type'] === 'image/jpeg') {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}

/*for creating table, which I don't recommend*/

$sql_query = "CREATE TABLE ".$_FILES['userfile']['name']." INT(6) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
timestamp FLOAT
)";
$mysqli->query($sql_query);

?>
```

/*First half of the code, but something came up, I will be back in an hour...*/

```
<?php
print '<form action="delete.php" method="post">
'.$_FILES['userfile']['name'].' <input type="submit" value="'.$_FILES['userfile']['name'].'" name="delete" />
</form>';
?>

<?php
$sql_query = "DROP TABLE ".$_POST['delete'];
$mysqli->query($sql_query);
?>
```

Instead of creating new tables for each file, I would recommend creating the table once, and insert the files like this:

```
<?php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table (name, type, timestamp) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssf", $_FILES['userfile']['name'], $_FILES['userfile']['name'], strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")));
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Similarly, if you want to delete:

```
<?php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM table WHERE name = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$_POST['delete']);
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Or if you know the id, you can delete it by it instead (is safer, because multiple files can own the same name, but id must be unique).

Comment: Terrible.. 1) it allows all files to be uploaded including PHP files which be be used to attack the server (backdoor) 2) The SQL injection is also real but not very clear how you would inject a CREATE TABLE statement and get acces to the other tables.. But still you have to protect it against SQL injections..

Comment: I know, prepared statements would be nice, but I'm in a hurry.

Comment: *"i know, prepared statements would be nice"* Won't fix issue one tho..

Comment: Does it not fix the SQL injection issue?

Comment: I'm actually looking for how create table can be sanitized. It seems removing special characters might be enough. But as I mentioned before, creating tables doesn't make sense in this case.

Comment: @kry im just getting this on my page ---            query($sql_query); ?>

Comment: You can't just add this code to your file - you have to tailor it for your needs. Judging from the closing tag, it is not recognized as a PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the big-picture overview of what you might wish to do.

#### 1. Identifying who uploaded what

You may want each uploader to be able to request a list of his uploaded files and, optionally, to remove one or more. Or, you might want to be able to list all uploaded videos, grouping them by the uploader.

For this, you want a login system. [Here is a post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56309840/1447509) that links to a couple of videos that take you through that process.

#### 2. Providing an upload system (client side)

You can write this from scratch, as you are doing, or you can use an already-invented wheel (rather than re-inventing it yourself). [This jQuery plugin](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php) is awesome - looks world-class and works perfectly. I have used it on dozens of projects. Plus, it comes with example code for both server-side and client-side. Take a look.

#### 3. Managing the uploaded files (server side)

On the server side, you might want to organize the uploaded files to some degree. There is no need to create much of a folder structure on the server since you have a database table to keep track of things, but at the least you might want to put them into a folder called "uploads" or "videos" or etc - just so that they are not stored in with the HTML files.

#### 4. Adding each uploaded video to a MySQL (now called MariaDB) table

If you use the jQuery File Upload plugin, you will already have a file that handles that back-end receipt of the uploaded file. It is in this file that you write the code to also post the data into the database.

Look at [this spot](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php#dynamicformdata) the docs for the jQuery file upload plugin. The plugin allows you to go fetch some additional data from the page (for example, you might have fields that ask the user for a tag, or a drop-down that lets users select a category) and you want to also insert those selections into the database when you upload the file. This is how you do that.

#### 5. Getting the list of videos from the MySQL table and listing them on a webpage

This is a simple matter of querying the database, creating some HTML code in a PHP variable, and then later outputting the PHP variable containing that HTML at the appropriate place in the web page. Personally, I prefer to keep as much of my PHP as possible at the top of the page - create the strings containing any PHP output - and then `echo` the HTML code at the appropriate place. Keeps the file tidy and easy to read.

This [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVMiDwiTMlc) will help you to grasp how to do that. Also see this post and this one.

Some notes to keep in mind:

a. You must name all of your web page files to end in `.php` instead of `.html`. There is almost no difference in how the pages will work - the sole difference is that any pages ending in `.php` can now process PHP code. Otherwise, they are identical. In fact, you can rename them now - try it - and they will work the same.

b. PHP code can be inserted anywhere in your web page -- you just place the PHP code between PHP_Start and PHP_END tags - it looks like this:

```
<?php
    $myvar = 'Bob';
?>
```

c. PHP is *very* unforgiving about missing end-of-statement semi-colons. If you forget one, the PHP script will abort at that spot ***with no notification***  This makes it a bit tricky to work with PHP. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54834111/1447509) for a couple of suggestions.

d. All PHP variables begin with a dollar sign. Weird, but true. Use the `echo` command to output PHP strings to the screen (for example, a PHP string containing HTML will display that HTML on the screen).

e. The PHP `$_SESSION` is super-useful. It is not difficult - it is just a way to store variables ***on the server***. Very useful for things like remembering if someone has logged in, remembering data about that user that is stored in a MySQL table, etc.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such an elaborate response!!! Also to add, I don't want the files to be loaded in browser as they are videos (500mb-2gb), just want to play them in buffer mode.

Comment: Not to worry, that is generally video files are handled by the browser - same as mp3 files. Do make a point to check out the other linked answers in my answer above (please upvote any you find helpful) -- you will find additional helpful tips and further detailed explanations -- and please ask any further questions if we can be of additional assistance.